# What Sith Lords were turned to the Light Side?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, star-wars-legends

I have heard of a ton of Jedi who have turned to the Dark Side and became a Sith (Exar Kun, Darth Malak). I've even heard of a few Jedi who have turned to the Dark Side and then found their way back to the Light (Revan, Anakin, Qel-Droma). But I cannot seem to recall any Sith who turned to the Light Side. I think I might have read of one, but I cannot remember the name or story.

**Are there any Sith who have turned to the Light? Hell, have there even been any Sith that have turned to the Light Side and then returned to the shadows of the Dark Side?**

Comment: Would you count Starkiller from The Force Unleashed? He was training to be a Sith but he wasn't a Sith Lord.

Comment: I guess that the Kylo Ren also does not fit the description, as he is first trained to be a Jedi, then gets converted to the Dark SIde (not as a Sith), then converts back

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Note: all individuals listed here are from Legends.*

## [Sajar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sajar)

Sajar, formerly Darth Sajar, was a member of the Dark Council of the Sith Empire during the Great Galactic War. After dueling with the Jedi Master Tol Braga, he renounced the dark side and his title as a Sith Lord to become Braga's Padawan and study the light side.

## [Kel'eth Ur](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kel%27eth_Ur)

Kel'eth Ur recorded a holocron that was stored in the Dark Temple on Dromund Kaas (capital of the Sith Empire). Though a Sith Lord, Kel'eth Ur's holocron promoted principles which agreed with the Jedi and the light side. Kel'eth Ur was apparently killed by the Sith Emperor for his heresy. Kel'eth Ur was a member of the [Light Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Sith), a group within the Sith Empire that supported the Empire but was aligned with the light side instead of the dark side.

## [Darth Gravid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Gravid)

Gravid was the Dark Lord of the Sith about five centuries before the events of the films. He did not totally renounce the dark side, but drifted to the light side during his reign as Dark Lord. He is notable in that he attempted to destroy Sith knowledge and treasures so that he could attempt to guide the Sith to what he viewed as a better path -- this attempt set back the Sith [Grand Plan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Plan) and forced later Sith like Darth Plagueis and Darth Sidious to attempt to re-discover lost Sith knowledge (such as [transfer essence](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Transfer_essence), which would allow a Sith to cheat death). His story is recounted from the Sith point of view in the novel [*Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_%28novel%29):

> A human Sith Lord whose short reign had elapsed some five centuries earlier, Gravid had been persuaded to believe that total commitment to the dark side would sentence the Sith Order to eventual defeat, and so had sought to introduce Jedi selflessness and compassion into his teachings and practice, forgetting that there can be no return to the light for an adept who has entered the dark wood; that the dark side will not surrender one to whom, by mutual agreement, it has staked a claim. Driven increasingly mad by his attempts to straddle the two realms, Gravid became convinced that the only way to safeguard the future of the Sith was to hide or destroy the lore that had been amassed through the generations—the texts, holocrons, and treatises—so that the Sith could fashion a new beginning for themselves that would guarantee success.

Comment: Ulic Qel-Droma too, perhaps?

Comment: @MarkEdward The question appears to be about persons who were originally Sith but later turned to the light side. He was originally a Jedi (and was mentioned in the question) so I don't think he is the kind of person the asker is looking for.

Comment: My mistake; I misread the question and somehow didn't even notice the reference to Ulic.

Comment: @MarkEdward No worries. The title is somewhat misleading.

Comment: So basically very very few. Is there ever talk about this in universe? Is it recognized that the Dark Side produces far more unwavering faith than the lightside?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski This question does restrict itself to individuals who were Sith to begin with, so if you include individuals who went Jedi --> Sith --> Jedi or who were Dark Jedi (but not Sith) you'd get more. That said, Yoda's statements that the dark side is the "easy" path and that it will "forever dominate your destiny" suggests that people are more likely to follow a light side --> dark side path than the reverse.

Comment: What about Starkiller from The Force Unleashed? He fits the criteria.

Comment: @RogueJedi I don't think he was ever considered a Sith *Lord*, though.

Comment: @Null I guess not. The question does ask for "Sith who have turned to the Light" though, who Starkiller qualifies as.

Comment: @RogueJedi I suggest asking the author of the question for clarification. If he doesn't require a Sith Lord, you should post Starkiller as an answer. I would upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

[Lord Praven](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Praven) was Sith (as a species) and a Sith Lord, and not only did he renounce the Dark Side, but he became a Jedi.

Answer (score 2):

In SWTOR, we meet [Lord Scourge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scourge_%28Sith%29). He's literally a Sith (as in the species) as well as a Sith Lord. Although he ultimately doesn't become a Jedi, he does turn away from the Dark Side of the Force and pledge his loyalty to the Jedi Order in to prevent the [Sith Emperor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Emperor) from destroying the entire Galaxy.

[image]

> *"Though the Emperor seeks to conceal his true plans, I have seen them.
>   That vision has driven me to this… I pledge my loyalty to you. Take me
>   to your Jedi Council on Tython, and I'll reveal why."*

Even after stepping away from the Dark Side, he still uses his powers aggressively, including the use of Force Choke and Force Push to slam people into objects

Comment: I know of Lord Scourge. As well as how he pledged his loyalty to the Jedi. However, he never renounced his hold on the Dark Side...

Comment: @DarthEspo - I would say that directly opposing the Sith Emperor would suggest that he'd had something of a change of heart.

Comment: I completely agree... However it doesn't answer my question. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, -1. Allying with light side users != turning to light side. By that metrics, you can say that Sidious turned to light side, because he (1) killed the previous Sith Lord and (2) fought the Jedi's enemies, CIS

Comment: @DVK - The major difference is that Sidious killed the previous Sith Lord in an attempt to make himself the Sith Lord, not because he necessarily opposed his overall plans or goals.

Comment: @Richard - Remaining a Sith Lord was kind of a major part of that guy's plans and goals. IYKWIM.

Comment: @DVK : Ick-whim?

Comment: @Omegacron - If you know what I mean :-P

Comment: @Richard - no, I don't... that's why I'm asking. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Starkiller was the very first example of this. He was trained by Darth Vader as his secret apprentice but ultimately went on to become a founding member of the Rebel Alliance. This of course is only in Legends and not the (Disney) canon. But, still, he was the first Sith turned Jedi that we saw.

Comment: Arguably, Starkiller does not qualify since he was never recognized as a Sith *Lord* -- merely a Sith apprentice.

Comment: Only the title actually uses the world 'lord'. The whole question body just refers to Sith.

Answer (score 0):

I have read all the answers, and for whatever reason, no one seems to remember Vader. He turned back near the end of his life. That is why he killed the Emperor in *Return of the Jedi*. He died as Anakin the light side Jedi.

Comment: Vader is listed in the question as an example of a Jedi who turned to the Dark Side and then turned back again. The question is looking for people who were Sith from the beginning.

Comment: @F1Krazy Oh ok. That makes sense.